# poll returns 0 but read does not block

Tags: c++, c, polling

I have been working on this piece of code for a while and for some reason poll returns zero even though there is data to be read in from the outFds pipe. For some reason if I read in some of the data and then run poll it returns the proper value, but this is not a solution. Has anybody seen this before and know what I should do?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/poll.h>

int main(void)
{
    int outFds[2];

    pipe(outFds);

    if(!fork()) {
        dup2(outFds[1], 1);

        close(outFds[0]);
        close(outFds[1]);

        // disable printf buffering
        setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);

        sleep(1);
        char buf[32];
        printf("blah");

        exit(0);
    }

    close(outFds[1]);

    char c;
    // Read 'b' into c. If this next line is not commented poll returns 1
    //read(outFds[0], &c, 1); 

    struct pollfd outFd;
    outFd.fd = outFds[0];
    outFd.events = POLLIN;
    printf("%d\n", poll(&outFd, 1, 0)); // poll returns 0 for some reason
}
```

Comment: Seems like you `poll` before the child has written to the pipe.  Did you try putting another `sleep` before the `poll`?

Comment: "poll returns zero even though there is data to be read in from the outFds pipe". How do you know that there is data to be read? Nothing in your code guarantees that the child `printf` executes before the parent `poll`. Especially since you have a `sleep` in the child before calling `printf`. So my money is on `poll` behaving correctly and your assumption not being correct.

Comment: Thanks Alan! I see now I had my sleep in the wrong place and that would explain why reading in a byte fixed the problem. I somehow forgot that read blocks haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the manpage:

> Specifying a timeout of zero causes poll() to return immediately, even
>   if no file descriptors are ready.

I would read this as a timespec struct with `tv_sec` and `tv_nsec` set to `0`, but it seems that putting a `nullptr` in has the same effect.